# How to modify the Create New Text File command

Tags: windows, cmd, registry, text-editor

I use the following registry import for a right-click context menu entry, NewTextFileAndOpen, (in Notepad).

[image: Right click context menu]

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,74,00,6f,00,6f,00,6c,00,73,00,5c,00,5f,\
  00,49,00,43,00,4f,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,\
  69,00,63,00,6f,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="cmd /c cd %V & echo.>NewTextFile.txt & start NewTextFile.txt"


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,74,00,6f,00,6f,00,6c,00,73,00,5c,00,5f,\
  00,49,00,43,00,4f,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,\
  69,00,63,00,6f,00,22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="cmd /c cd %V & echo.>NewTextFile.txt & start NewTextFile.txt"
```

When I open again the notepad, using the right-click context menu, **NewTextFileAndOpen**, any new edits are always saved in `NewTextFile.txt`. I want to save in a text file with another name.

I ask for your help in saving a new auto name:

```
NewTextFile.txt
NewTextFile (1).txt
NewTextFile (2).txt
NewTextFile (3).txt
NewTextFile (4).txt
```

I tried to modify the following command line :

```ini
@="cmd /c cd %V & echo.>NewTextFile.txt & start NewTextFile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file with a name like `NewTextFileAndOpen.cmd` or another name you like in the directory `C:\Tools` or another directory of your choice with the following lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == "" exit /B
set "NewFileName=%~1\NewTextFile.txt"
if not exist "%NewFileName%" goto CreateAndOpen
set "FileNumber=1"
:FindFreeNumber
set "NewFileName=%~1\NewTextFile (%FileNumber%).txt"
if exist "%NewFileName%" set /A "FileNumber+=1" & goto FindFreeNumber
:CreateAndOpen
echo(>"%NewFileName%"
start "" /D "%~1" "%NewFileName%"
endlocal
```

This batch file requires being started with a folder path as first argument string. It does nothing and immediately exits if it is started without any argument string.

There is no verification made if the passed argument string references really an existing directory, but that could be changed for safe usage of the batch file from within a command prompt window by inserting after the first **IF** condition the command line:

```
for %%I in ("%~1") do if not exist "%%~fI\" do echo No directory: "%~1"& pause & exit /B
```

The registry file with name `NewTextFileAndOpen.reg` stored also in `C:\Tools` should contain the lines:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,\
  6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,\
  00,31,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /D /S /C \"\"C:\\Tools\\NewTextFileAndOpen.cmd\" \"%V\"\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,\
  6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,\
  00,31,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /D /S /C \"\"C:\\Tools\\NewTextFileAndOpen.cmd\" \"%V\"\""
```

The registry value `Icon` is in this case of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` with the value:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-102
```

There can be used also the following registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,\
  6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,\
  00,31,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /D /S /C \"\"C:\\Tools\\NewTextFileAndOpen.cmd\" \"%V\"\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,\
  6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,\
  00,31,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /D /S /C \"\"C:\\Tools\\NewTextFileAndOpen.cmd\" \"%V\"\""
```

The registry value `Icon` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` has with this registry file the value:

```
%SystemRoot%\notepad.exe,-2
```

Or there is used the following registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Tools\\_ICO\\notepad.ico\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /D /S /C \"\"C:\\Tools\\NewTextFileAndOpen.cmd\" \"%V\"\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen]
@="New Text File and Open"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Tools\\_ICO\\notepad.ico\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\NewTextFileAndOpen\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /D /S /C \"\"C:\\Tools\\NewTextFileAndOpen.cmd\" \"%V\"\""
```

The registry value `Icon` is of type `REG_SZ` with the value:

```
"C:\Tools\_ICO\notepad.ico"
```

Please modify the path of `cmd.exe` if *Windows* is installed on a different drive like `D:\Windows`. It is better to use the fully qualified file name of `cmd.exe` instead of just `cmd`. It is better using a registry value of type `REG_SZ` and not of `REG_EXPAND_SZ` for the command to execute.

The registry file can be imported from within a command prompt window with execution of the command line:

```
reg.exe IMPORT "C:\Tools\NewTextFileAndOpen.reg"
```

There are no elevated privileges of a local administrator required for the registry import using this command line.

The batch file and the command line imported into the registry are designed for working also for directories like:

```
C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%
\\Server\Share\Folder\SubFolder
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` ... first argument string with surrounding `"` removed.
- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.
- DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) for the reason using `echo(` instead of `echo.`